# Success ajax request but can't see my data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

So I try to call data from MySQL database using jQuery.ajax but I'm not able to see the result in my web. I have my  [estacionamiento table here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3SRV.jpg). Then my api.php file and index.php respectively

```js
<?php
  include("connect.php");
  $link=Connection();

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT `estado` FROM `estacionamiento` ", $link);     //query
  $array = mysql_fetch_row($result);                          //fetch result

  echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

```html
  <script src="js/jQuery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  $(function ()
  {
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // 2) Send a http request with AJAX http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    $.ajax({
      url: 'api.php',                  //the script to call to get data
      data: "",                        //you can insert url argumnets here to pass to api.php
                                       //for example "id=5&parent=6"
      dataType: 'json',                //data format
      success: function(data)          //on recieve of reply
      {
        alert('Successfully called');
        console.log(data);
        $('#output').html("<b> estado: </b>"+data);
        }
    });
  });

  </script>
```

I'm able too see the alert successfully called but in console log it shows that the data is [""] but it's clearly that I have some data in 'estado'
You can see the result here. (http://estacionamiento.site88.net/)

Edit: Now I have to fetch many variables, I would receive any suggestion

I was thinking something like this but It isn't working

```js
<?php
  include("connect.php");
  $link=Connection();
  $data= array();
  $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `estacionamiento' ORDER BY timeStamp DESC",
  while ($array = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $data[] = $array;
  }

  echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

Comment: Ajax is expecting an array, right? Or at least as with an object name. So, return it as one. `echo  json_encode(array( 'myObject' => $array ));` and receive it in ajax as `data.myObject`. Not great at this, but I have a similar solution working myself right now.

Comment: Seems liek there might be an error in the sql statement. Or it's not connecting to the database. Can you add some error checking.

Comment: if (false === $array) {
die(mysql_error());
}

Comment: you need to loop over results.

Comment: Do a `var_dump($array);` and let us know what do you really get..! Also you need to loop over your results as : `$data = array();  while ($array = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { $data[] = $array; }`

Comment: Your `api.php`, I guess, will only return `["libre"]`.

Comment: Try to use json_encode($array, 1). Do you have tested that your server scripting is returning data?

Comment: @AlgernopK. Thanks for answering. I tried using ur way and It looks like it works similar but in the end I've received same result. At least in console.log I see more details:
Array[1]
0: 
""length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]

Comment: @Brett I don't think that's the problem since I've been using the same connection with my Arduino. My Arduino sends and insert data to MySQL database. There aren't mistakes there. Thanks anyway !

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai Sorry but I'm relatevily new to java,jquery php and css (less than a week) so I don't really know where to write var_dump($array); (in api.php or index.php)

Comment: @AfshanShujat I've just tried and It doesn't work. And Seems like it's returning data but it is " " even though my table is filled with strings. Would you have any other suggestion?

Comment: @LoganWayne Hey Logan, How is it going ? I know I told you that I was working just with one variable but...I knew eventually that I had to manage many variables. So in order to avoid another question, how can I fetch many variables from MySQL database in java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `api.php`, I guess, will only return `["libre"]`. Or you want only a single data to be returned?

```
<?php

    /* ESTABLISH CONNECTION; REPLACE NECESSARY PARAMETERS BELOW */
    $link = new mysqli("Host", "Username", "Password", "Database");

    /* CHECK CONNECTION */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    $stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT estado FROM estacionamiento WHERE estado <> '' ORDER BY estado DESC"); /* PREPARE YOUR QUERY */
    $stmt->execute(); /* EXECUTE QUERY */
    $stmt->bind_result($estado); /* BIND RESULT TO THIS VARIABLE */
    $stmt->fetch(); /* FETCH RESULT */
    $stmt->close(); /* CLOSE PREPARED STATEMENT */

    echo $estado;

?>
```

Then, on your ajax (*since, you'll be returning a single data that is not an array, I removed the `dataType: 'json'`*):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'api.php',  
    success: function(data)
    {
        alert('Successfully called');
        console.log(data); /* WILL RETURN AS `libre` */
        $('#output').html("<b> estado: </b>"+data); /* #output WILL HAVE `estado: libre` */
    }
});
```

Maybe you'll be interested with [jQuery.get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) since you're only getting a single data:

```
$.get( "api.php", function( data ) {
    alert("Successfully called");
    console.log(data);
    $("#output").html('<b> estado: </b>'+data);
});
```

Comment: Hey Logan ! Yes indeed I just want to receive a single data that belongs to estado column.  I've tried using your code but still unable to see something. Although in console It says undefined because of console.log(data.estado);
And When I rewrite mysql for mysqli, it doesn't even show the alert of "Successfully called". In my opinion, my web hosting probably doesn't support (dunno really, kind of new to this java,php,mysql stuff)

Comment: I can give you an example of `mysqli_*`. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I just checked your code and It's great ! Nevertheless, I was able to figure out where was my problem. I've been filling my table "estacionamiento" with string so many times that I forgot to clear first inputs which hasn't data in 'estado' column so there was nothing to display in my web. I thought that ajax call will retrieve last data. Now, my new question is How to retrieve last data from my database? Should I read and erase every time my table is being filled by new data?

Comment: Use `DESC` or use a condition to only get the rows that has content. Check the updated query on my answer.

Comment: Hey Logan, How is it going ? I know I told you that I was working just with one variable but...I knew eventually that I had to manage many variables. So in order to avoid another question, how can I fetch many variables from MySQL database in java?

Comment: @JeancarloC. - just select more columns from your `SELECT` query and output it from there